# ORDER BY optimization for a large table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am currently aggregating posts from different social networks. Currently I have 50-100 million posts from Facebook, Twitter, Youtube, Instagram , Pinterest.

Consider a table `posts`

```
posts
{
    id  int(11),
    user_id  int(11),
    url varchar(256), 
    image varchar(256), 
    source int(11),  // Social Network Source 
    created bigint(20), // Publish time of the post 
    visible int(1) // Public or Private Posts
}
```

Using `InnoDB`

Indexes :

```
primary key on id
user_id,source
user_id,created
```

Space usage

```
Type    Usage 
Data    45,876.0    MiB
Index   4,959.0 MiB
Total   50,835.0    MiB
```

Using Amazon RDS with 7.5 GB RAM.

The queries I am executing are as follows

```
select id 
from posts 
where user_id={user_id} 
  and visible=1  
order by created desc 
  LIMIT 20 ;


select id 
from posts 
where user_id={user_id} 
  and source={your_network} 
  and visible=1 
order by created desc 
  LIMIT 20 ;
```

For users with > 500k posts sometimes my queries take a really long time.

I have run explain and you can see the results below

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id
FROM  `posts` 
WHERE user_id =123529745 and source=1 and visible=1
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 20

id    select_type       table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra 
1       SIMPLE          posts   ref     user_id_2,user_id_4,user_id_3,created   created 4       const   954174  Using where; Using index

id    select_type       table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra 
1       SIMPLE          posts   ref     user_id_2,user_id_4,user_id_3,created   created 4       const   742308  Using where;
```

Can you please suggest me any optimizations?

Comment: Can you explain your indexes a bit better. Looks to me like an index on just user_id would do the job.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson How does an index on `user_id` optimize `ORDER BY created`?

Comment: Index on (user_id,source) filters posts by network source. Index on (user_id,created) is for order by optimization.

Comment: @Barmar, I was thinking more along the lines of it using a user_id index in the where. Unless I misread the explain, it's using the created index and testing each one for user_id?

Comment: This guy must work for the CIA or something. Are you spying on me?

Answer (score 5):

This is your query:

```
SELECT id
FROM  `posts` 
WHERE user_id =123529745 and source=1 and visible=1
ORDER BY created DESC
```

You are doing only equality comparisons in the `where` and then sorting by `created`.

A single index on:  `posts(user_id, source, visible, created, id)` should allow the entire query to be satisfied only by the index -- first finding the right rows, then sorting by them, and then fetching the id.

Comment: Will it also satisfy the query SELECT id
FROM  `posts` 
WHERE user_id =123529745 and visible=1
ORDER BY created DESC ?

Comment: @Nikhil . . . No.  MySQL has a pretty good description of how indexes get used (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  MySQL might still satisfy all columns from the index, saving on the fetch from the original pages, which may be the root of the performance problem.